# Throw an exception or return default value in base class

Tags: c++

I have a base class that defines methods as virtual and those methods has nothing inside, just the declaration. I have a class that derives from the base class and doesn't implements all the methods and here is where the problem appears. If we call a method that isn't implemented on the derived class, but in the base, it crashes.

Example (it crashes):

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
public:
    virtual std::string ref() {}
};

class Bar : public Foo {};

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    auto foo = new Bar;
    auto bar = foo->ref();

    return 0;
}
```

**Q: What is the best solution in this case.**

**1)** - Return a default (empty) value.

```
virtual std::string ref()
{
    return "";
}
```

**2)** - Throw an exception that you can't call methods directly from the base class.

```
virtual std::string ref()
{
    throw std::runtime_error(":(");
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why not simply `virtual std::string ref() = 0;`? But depends on use case as usual.

Comment: I can't because I need also to return an instance of the base class.

Comment: Then it's probably best to choose a reasonable default value, instead of throwing an exception.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Why? As a *workaround*, the exception may actually be the better solution. If his class design has so extremely gotten out of his hands that he just somehow needs an instance of the base class yet never calls the function, throwing an exception if it still happens sounds nicer than "swallowing" the error. Of course, an `assert(false);` may be even nicer.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Good point, the `assert()` proposal in particular.

Comment: @SH.0x90: If the base class doesn't have useful definitions for a function, I would _strongly_ question your claim that you need to return an instance of the base class.  Alter the code so that these two things do not coincide.

Answer (score 4):

This is what pure virtuals are for:

```
virtual std::string ref() = 0;
```

now the compiler won't let you instantiate an instance of a derived type that doesn't define that function.

Comment: I can't because I need also to return an instance of the base class.

Comment: @SH.0x90: In this case, any long-term solution will involve a redesign of your class structure.

Answer (score 2):

> If we call a method that isn't implemented on the derived class, but
>   in the base, it crashes.

This does not strictly apply to your example code:

```
virtual std::string ref() {}
```

An implementation is there; you get a crash **because the implementation doesn't return anything**. The same would likely happen here, for example:

```
#include <string>

std::string f() {}

int main()
{
   std::string x = f();
   x = "";
}
```

(I say "likely" because it's undefined behaviour, so the crash is not guaranteed.)

As for your problem:

If you need to call functions which do not conceptually exist, then you have a design problem; chances are that your base class tries to fulfill too many responsibilities at the same time.

Otherwise, use abstract classes. You can make a class abstract by declaring at least one function **pure virtual**:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    virtual std::string ref() = 0; // pure virtual function
};
```

Please note three further things:

- You almost certainly need a virtual destructor in your base class.
- Except of the destructor, consider making your public functions non-virtual and your virtual functions private, the public non-virtual ones calling the private virtual ones.
- Your function looks like a candidate for a const function.

Final example:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    virtual ~Foo() {}
    std::string ref() const { return refImpl(); }
private:
    virtual std::string refImpl() const = 0;
};
```

Comment: `if you need to call functions which do not conceptually exist, then you have a design problem.`

 - Imagine a situation where you have several classes that derives from the base. Let's say that the base is `animal` and we have classes just like `elephant`, `dog`, `cat` that is `animal`. Each one behaves in a different way, but to implements the polymorphism I need to implement the methods on the base. - The `cat` has a method `meow`, `dog` doesn't, but the method `meow` will be available to call because it's on the base. What happen if I call `meow` in a `dog` instance? Crash.

Comment: @SH.0x90: You are describing a perfect *design problem*. Obviously, `animal` should NOT have a `meow` method, because it is not an operation which every animal can perform. The crash is just a symptom, not the problem.

Comment: Rather, `animal` should have a method like `makeNoises`, which every animal could perform in its own individual way. And somehwere else in your code, you are only interested in animals making noises, not whether it's meowing or barking. That's OOP.

Comment: Yes, I understand, let me complete the comment and you see if you continue with your answer about it and what you would do in order to redesign. - Imagine now that I have a method that can return a pointer to `animal`, what this mean? I can return `elephant`, `dog`, `cat` in this method because logically any of them are `animal`. - Or, for example, a vector that accept pointers of animal and you can use `at` method to retrieve the pointer. If I don't have the methods as virtual on the base class I can't use the methods on the returned pointer. (in advance, forget about dynamic_cast).

Comment: Vectors and pointers have nothing to do with it. Let me repeat: You need an abstract operation which makes sense for ALL subclasses. Otherwise, don't use OOP.